Is it enough just to check the effect of a boost in the z-direction to prove the covariance of an expression for the lorentz transformations?
Is it enough to check the effect of a boost in the z-direction to prove the Lorentz invariance of an expression for the $L^\uparrow _+$ transformations? My argument why this is true is that we can then just rotate the space with a $R(3x3)\in O(3)$ and still stay inside $L^\uparrow _+$.
I also guess for $L^\downarrow_+$, $L^\downarrow_-$ and $L^\uparrow_+$ this wouldn't work anymore, since the boost is an element of $L^\uparrow _+$ only...
